# DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password. ");, Javap Mitigation

Tags: credentials

Hard-Coding using JavaDB, and netbeans. I wrote a simple table, then I wrote a simple java program to run and connect to the database, code seems to be running well. I wrote the code hard-coded purposefully with the username/password to the database. Wrote the code, an, awesome. I am using terminal and javap -c, with DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password. ");o read all the file, Im hoping that's considered hard-coded hacking, I need a way to mitigate it, or patch it. I was looking at Argon2 for java, but simply can't understand it yet. These are pics of running the code, connection, database, and in terminal I ran javap -c and it red me out the username/password info, how can I block. AlsoI installed a Debugging Plugin into NB tjat worked once and did like javap, but it's only worked once. if some one could help me with it or a dfferent type of mitigation - patch Id really appreciate it.
Main Code with exception:
 import java.sql.SQLException;

```
public class HardCodeMitigation {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
  // TODO code application logic here
  abc a1 = new abc();
 }
}

Second code w/DriverMan with passwords Hard-coded
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class abc {

 public abc() throws SQLException {

  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/IT_Entity", "cain", "cain");
  System.out.println("Connection Created");
 }

}

Javap - c showing passwords: Chads - MacBook - Pro: ~chadbyars$ cd / Users / chadbyars / NetBeansProjects / hardcodemitigation / src
Chads - MacBook - Pro: src chadbyars$ javac abc.java
Chads - MacBook - Pro: src chadbyars$ java abc
Error: Main method not found in class abc, please define the main method as:
 public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
Chads - MacBook - Pro: src chadbyars$ javap - c abc
Compiled from "abc.java"
class abc {
 public abc() throws java.sql.SQLException;
 Code:
  0: aload_0
 1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: ldc           # 2 // String jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/IT_Entity
 6: ldc #3                  // String cain
       8: ldc           # 3 // String cain
 10: invokestatic #4                  // Method java/sql/DriverManager.getConnection:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;
      13: astore_1
      14: getstatic     # 5 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 17: ldc #6                  // String Connection Created
      19: invokevirtual # 7 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 22: return
}
Chads - MacBook - Pro: src chadbyars$
```

Comment: please paste your images in the question and not linked to an external resource.

Comment: when i submit pics its not showing theimages, I just posted the codes and the javap -c output